# Customize JTable, unexpected behaviours

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Attempting to create a custom JTable structure, I started with a very simple project to better understand. Unfortunately, as soon as I start to customize stuff, I get weird behaviours and I would like you to help me understand them. Thank you very much.

Here is my small project :

```
public class Tableau extends JFrame {

    public Tableau() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800,600);
        setContentPane(new Panel());
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Tableau();
    }
    private static class Panel extends JPanel {
        private JTable table = new Table(4, 4);
        public Panel() {
            add(table);
        }
    }

    private static class Table extends JTable {
        private Renderer randerer = new Renderer();
        public Table(int row, int col) {
            super(new Model(row, col));
            setAutoResizeMode(AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
            setDefaultRenderer(String.class, randerer);
            setDefaultEditor(String.class, randerer);
        }

        private class Renderer implements TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor {
            String previousContent = "";
            JTextPane rendererComponent = new JTextPane();
            public Renderer() {
                super();setOpaque(true);
            }
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                rendererComponent.setText((String)value);
                rendererComponent.setBorder(hasFocus ? BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED) : null);
                rendererComponent.setBackground(isSelected ? Color.PINK : Color.GREEN);
                FontMetrics fm = rendererComponent.getFontMetrics(rendererComponent.getFont());
                if(((String)value).length()!=0) {rendererComponent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(fm.stringWidth((String)value),fm.getHeight()));}
                else {rendererComponent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, fm.getHeight()));}
                return rendererComponent;
            }

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
                rendererComponent.setText((String)value);
                rendererComponent.setBackground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionBackground() : Color.MAGENTA);
                if(isSelected) {rendererComponent.selectAll();}
                previousContent = (String)value;
                return rendererComponent;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getCellEditorValue() {
                return rendererComponent.getText();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean stopCellEditing() {
                fireEditingStoppedEvent();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void cancelCellEditing() {
                rendererComponent.setText(previousContent);
                fireEditingCanceledEvent();
            }

            protected void fireEditingStoppedEvent() {
                for(CellEditorListener l : listeners) {l.editingStopped(new ChangeEvent(this));}
            }

            protected void fireEditingCanceledEvent() {
                for(CellEditorListener l : listeners) {l.editingCanceled(new ChangeEvent(this));}
            }

            private List<CellEditorListener> listeners = new LinkedList<CellEditorListener>();
            @Override
            public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
                listeners.add(l);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
                listeners.remove(l);
            }

        }
    }

    private static class Model implements TableModel {
//        private ColumnModel colonnes = new ColumnModel();
        private List<List<Cellule>> colonnes = new LinkedList<List<Cellule>>();
        private int rowCount = 0;
//        private List<Cellule> cellules = new LinkedList<Cellule>();

        private static class Cellule {
            public Cellule() {}
            public Cellule(Object content) {this.content = content;}
            private Object content;
            private Object getContent() {return content;}
            private void setContent(Object newContent) {content = newContent;}
        }

        public Model(int row, int col) {
            for(int j=0; j<col; j++) {
                insertColumn(j);
            }
            for(int i=0; i<row; i++) {
                insertRow(i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return rowCount;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return colonnes.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
            String result = "";
            for (; columnIndex >= 0; columnIndex = columnIndex / 26 - 1) {
                result = (char)((char)(columnIndex%26)+'A') + result;
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return colonnes.isEmpty() ? Object.class : getValueAt(columnIndex, 0).getClass();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return colonnes.get(columnIndex).get(rowIndex).getContent();
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            colonnes.get(columnIndex).get(rowIndex).setContent(aValue);
            fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this, rowIndex, rowIndex, columnIndex, TableModelEvent.UPDATE));
        }

        protected void fireTableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            for(TableModelListener l : listeners) {
                l.tableChanged(null);
            }
        }

        public void insertColumn(int index) {
            List<Cellule> newColumn = new LinkedList<Cellule>();
            for(int i = 0; i<getRowCount(); i++) {
                Cellule newCell = new Cellule("");
                newColumn.add(newCell);
            }
            colonnes.add(index, newColumn);
            fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this, 0, getRowCount(), index, TableModelEvent.INSERT));
        }

        public void insertRow(int index) {
            for(List<Cellule> colonne : colonnes) {
                Cellule newCell = new Cellule("");
                colonne.add(index, newCell);
            }
            rowCount++;
            fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this, index, index, TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS, TableModelEvent.INSERT));
        }

        public void removeColumn(int index) {
            colonnes.remove(index);
            fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this, 0, getRowCount(), index, TableModelEvent.DELETE));
        }

        public void removeRow(int index) {
            for(List<Cellule> row : colonnes) {
                row.remove(index);
            }
            rowCount--;
            fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this, index, index, TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS, TableModelEvent.DELETE));
        }

        private List<TableModelListener> listeners = new LinkedList<TableModelListener>();
        @Override
        public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
            listeners.add(l);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
            listeners.remove(l);
        }

    }

}
```

Basically, we have a JFrame (class Tableau), containing a JPanel (class Panel) containing a JTable (class Table). This Table uses a TableModel (class Model) and a JTextPane (class Renderer) that will serve for both rendering and editing the table content.

Here are my problems :

1) If I click a cell, it becomes white (which I don't understand how it is possible given the code of the renderer...). If I write something, first, nothing appears in the cell, but then, when I move the focus, the text appears...

2) If I click a cell and then move the focus using arrow keys, only then the selections seems to be done correctly. The red border is correctly displayed, etc. Why is the selection incorrect when I just click, without using arrows ?

Thanks !

Comment: These are really 4 separate questions, some of which can be answered in the documentation.

Comment: Ok for 4. I will remove it from here, create a new question with my attempts. 1 and 2 are both linked and are the ones I have most interest in. 3 is just to have an opinion, but I can remove it. Thank you

Comment: 3 is answered in the tutorials, there is an easy way to change the selection operation.

Comment: 1) for why reason is there bunch of TableCellEditors (something about loop in List), 2) how much JTables is already linked with one model (JTable table;), because there you need pass JTable in renderer/editor class, 3) then there JTextPane could be local variable, not reason to extends, 4) putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE); == stopCellEditing, then stopCellEditing is contraproductive

Comment: 5) whats reason to for return colonnes.isEmpty() ? rowCount : colonnes.get(0).size();, Cell can have null value too 6) notifiers in Table model are wrong, btw fireTableChanged reset tablemodel, not good idea, you can very simple to lost all custom TableCellRenderer/Editors .... etc

Comment: 7) forgot about a.m. structure and to split  a.m. (to the 6th) question as a new separate threads, start with a new question how to create a AbstractTableModel based on util.List and with proper notifiers, then how ... Custom Renderer and Editor, then about JTable, etc...

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. But I didn't understand all of them, I'm sorry.
1, What do you mean ? 2, You're right. I edited. 3) It was for convenient reason as it was a small example, but you're right. Edited. 4)Not sure I understand why, but ok, I removed the "terminateEditOnFocusLost". 5)Not sure I completely understood your point, but I edited. 6) What am I supposed to fire ? I just notify about the rows, columns or cells that are concerned with a modification, no?

Comment: 7) Ok, let's give up all sides problems, I will read more tutorials about it and write better code, but what I really look for is the explanation of where my problems 1) and 2) come from. Thank you so much for your time